# How can I register to FIDE being in a different country where I don't have citizenship or residency?

Tags: fide, tournament

I come from Bangladesh and I am doing my bachelor's degree in Australia as an international student. Unfortunately, I didn't register with FIDE under the Bangladesh Chess Federation when I was in my country and I am not able to go back to my country within the next few years. However, I really want to start playing rated tournaments. How can I now register so that I can play FIDE rated tournaments?

I have been thinking of these two possibilities:

1. Register under FIDE flag if possible?
2. Register for a FIDE rated tournament in Bangladesh. Since I won't be showing up in the tournament, is it going to impact my registration?

Comment: maybe try contacting the bangladesh federation rating officer Md Haroon or Rashid
https://ratings.fide.com/fide_directory.phtml?list=799

Comment: Look at your [state's chess federation](https://auschess.org.au/) rules for registration, you can probably register there and have a correct FIDE registration

Answer (score 1):

If you play your first FIDE open tournament and obtain a FIDE rating, it is highly likely that you will be registered with the federation that organized that tournament.
Later, if you wish, you can switch to another federation (It is not a difficult process).
In general, being part of a national chess federation does not require citizenship of that country.

However, I advise you to focus on your academic duties. If you want to play FIDE chess tournaments while in college, you need to plan carefully. Otherwise, you can be in trouble. It is difficult to succeed on both fields. For example, you can play during the summer. Online chess is more flexible. Good luck!